# People can't download our specific product in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

We've recently released our game onto Android Market but are suffering from a major issue. We are getting emails and bug reports from people all over the world that they aren't able to download our game.

Searching the web for people with similar issues we've found that some are experiencing similar problems, though they can't download any applications at all from the Market. The people we have been dealing with can download everything else except for our game. The people reporting issues have enough memory on their devices both internal and external.

Does anyone have any clue to what the problem can be?

Best Regards,
Alex

Edit:
Since the problem is download related we've been speculating in that its the Android Manifest file we've have.

What is the first thing that happens when a user downloads an application from Android Market? Because when we try downloading our product the download "starts" and then the error message "Download Unsuccessful" flashes over the bar.

Our product is a paid application and the transaction is successful but then when the user tries to download it they get the error.

It seems as if the error started occurring after we submitted our first updated, though minor and not any game changing I really don't understand how this can effect the Market behavior.

Comment: Do the users report any particular error when they download?

Comment: Some more information would be good, eg answers to the following questions: Does the download start? If the download starts, does it finish? Does it work for you? How big is the download? etc etc

Comment: Okay, the download starts but gets canceled straight away and it says "Download Unsuccessful". Our game is pretty large but its less than the cap at 50Mb. Even though we are on a wi-fi and not downloading the game via the cellular network it fails. The game works perfectly fine for us when we're developing it, but we aren't downloading it from the market obviously.  It seems as if it happened after we uploaded our first update, because it was after that we started receiving reports.

Comment: Since the problem is download related we've been speculating in that its the Android Manifest file we've edited thats the problem.

Comment: I don't think it is the xml header -- a) Zwitscher also has utf8 and b) I'd expect the plublish application to choke on it already.

Comment: Okay so its not the mainfest then what can it be? What is the first thing that happens when you try to download an application from Android Market, since it seems as if it's there the problem is.

Comment: Yea, i tried posting the whole XML file but was just able to post the xml header, the rest of the text was hidden for some reason.

Comment: How about providing the name of the game so we can go see what the problem is?

Comment: Golf Battle 3D - http://www.golfbattle3d.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 47MB! Here's what my Samsung Galaxy S says:

```
D/DownloadManager( 2973): download aborted - not enough free space in internal storage
D/vending ( 6634): [174] DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver.handleDownloadCompletedAction(): Got a download completed intent.
I/vending ( 6634): [174] DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver.startNextDownload(): Found Paused URI null
I/vending ( 6634): [174] DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver.startNextDownload(): No more paused downloads.
I/vending ( 6634): [174] DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver.getDownloadStatus(): Unexpected status from download - 498
W/vending ( 6634): [174] DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver.handleDownloadCompletedAction(): Couldn't find pathname for completed download URI
: content://downloads/download/188 -- assuming the download failed.
D/vending ( 6634): [174] LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): 9122500792911627655 / DOWNLOAD_FAILED
E/DataRouter( 2577): [*] Received suspend/ resume event but DUN is not up so neglect
```

Not enough internal storage space, unsurprisingly.

What is your installLocation set to? Should be preferExternal (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)

**ADDED LATER**

Hoo boy, this sucks...

You can browse the source code for Android's download manager here: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#UMpkw0xvvPU/src/com/android/providers/downloads/Helpers.java

Extrapolating a bit you can do what it does to find out how much space is left in the download cache directory:

```
File base = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
long bytesAvailable = getAvailableBytes(base);

public static long getAvailableBytes(File root) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(root.getPath());
    // put a bit of margin (in case creating the file grows the system by a few blocks)
    long availableBlocks = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() - 4;
    return stat.getBlockSize() * availableBlocks;
}
```

My Samsung Galaxy S reports **just 30MB is free** in this cache, hence the problem. The phone's overall internal storage however is enormous... I have at least 1.5GB free.

Clearly there is some download cache limiting policy at work. Very annoying for you.

**Free bytes in /cache for a few phones**

Samsung Galaxy S : **30756KB**

Nexus One:  **94352KB**

Orange San Francisco: **38988KB**

Comment: Odd, the Mainfest now states installetion loocation to "auto" "The application may be installed on the external storage, but the system will install the application on the internal storage by default. If the internal storage is full, then the system will install it on the external storage. Once installed, the user can move the application to either internal or external storage through the system settings."

Comment: You don't want "auto". 47MB is enormous... you definitely want "preferExternal". You may want to think about redesigning your game to download at least some of your content to external storage rather than shipping it all in the .apk.

Comment: Our application is now upp on the market with the new manifest and still we cant download it.. :/

Comment: How come Apple can provide applications larger then 50Mb while Google cant provide applications that are 47Mb? Though Apple doesn't let you download your applications larger then 20Mb over the cellular network, but still. If you are connected to a WiFi you can download any navigator you want and all of them are 500Mb+

Comment: @Alex I think you have a genuine grievance here... I have updated my answer with a new observation. I'd be interested to know if you get the same result from the sample code I posted.

Comment: Cheers thanks for your help, I think the code you posted will come in handy to figure out the cache-size on other devices such as the HTC Legend and Nexus One which are the ones we have available at work for testing. Guess we'll have to redesign our game some for Android Market. Thanks again!

Comment: Added a few measurements from the handsets lying around this office. Suspect the popular HTC Desire will have a very small cache, but can't lay my hands on one this minute.

Comment: Awesome, cheers, thanks again. I'm at the moment setting up my Eclipse to run the code you've shared on my Nexus One and the HTC Legend I have at my disposal. I'll get back to you when I'm successful.

Comment: 98017KB is what I got from our Nexus One, having problems running it on our Legend, ADB ain't able to find the device when I connect it to my computer.

Comment: If ADB can't see it you haven't got the right USB driver installed. IIRC there should be an "HTC Sync" folder on the SD Card that came with the phone which allegedly contains the installer. If that's not available you can get it from htc.com fairly easily.

Comment: Ye, cheers, but its just that I've been reinstalling those drivers over and over again several times without any luck. Gonna give it a shot again just to get the cache size information.

Comment: You could always create an apk which shows the info as a Toast notification or something, and install via web or email. No need for ADB then.

Comment: 154 251Kb - can this really be correct. It claims that our HTC Tatoo running 1.6 has 150Mb cache? Starting to doubt myself..

Comment: Why not? The internal storage is 512MB total, the 1.6 image is probably significantly smaller than 2.x. I think 256MB was the normal reserved space for apps (i.e. /data) on 1.x, so it's easy to imagine the remaining space being 100MB for the OS and 150MB left over for cache.

Comment: Aah well guess so. Thanks you, and thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Just for info: My Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 has ~450Mb. Huge difference with the Galaxy S.

Comment: could anyone confirm if the new firmware update by samsung solves this problem?

Comment: Yes, I've heard of people with SGS Android > 2.1 without this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

On March 5, 2012, Google announced a new policy of allowing up to two "expansion files" of up to 2 Gigabytes each.  The APK is still limited to 50MB.  Here is the announcement:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

Since the downloads of such additional files occur separately from the download of your APK, it seems likely that you could solve your problem by moving a chunk of your APK into an expansion file so as to keep the APK size within the smallest download cache limits that you anticipate (e.g., 30MB).