# Android Market filesize limit. 50MB or 4GB?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a game I want to publish, but my apk size is 105 MB. I saw that Google announces they want to raise their limit to 4GB, but I just tried to upload my 105 MB file and I received an error message saying my application was too big. 
Is the 4GB limit is a rumor or it's something that we will see pretty soon?
Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 7):

> Is the 4GB limit is a rumor or it's something that we will see pretty soon?

It is not "just a rumor", as Google announced plans for this at the Google I|O 2011 conference. They indicated the feature would be made available in June, though it is entirely possible that their schedule will slip. Also, bear in mind that it is very likely that the 50MB limit will still be there, but that there will be ways of shipping a pair of additional 2GB files along with the app to contain game assets and such, with instructions for how developers can use those files.

Comment: Notes for the announcement are at http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/events/io/2011/static/notesfiles/AndroidMarket.pdf and the video is up at http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-market-for-developers.html

Answer (score 4):

The support for 4GB apps is out now. As mentioned above, the APK is still limited to 50MB, but two additional 2GB files can be provided.

Read more at:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the theorical limit, there is a practical one which is the size of the "/cache" partition.
For instance, on my Galaxy S, this partition is limited to 30MB !
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4850889/868314)

Comment: This is just crazy :S

Answer (score 2):

APK file size: Maximum supported size is 50MB.

http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469

Answer (score 2):

The support for Large Apps in the market announced at Google I/O does not allowed for APK files bigger than 50MB.  [Instead, the Market will allow you to upload two resource files which can be up to 2GB in size along with your APK.](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/11/io-2011-google-increases-app-size-limit-to-4gb-tweaks-the-return-policy/)

However, this is not yet available at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. but Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK, Read more about it here ,

[APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. The limit of the APK is still 50MB
2. You can add bundles up to 4GB (Each app can have 2 expansion files, each one up to 2GB)